# How to change color of math output of MaTeX

Tags: matex

I like to work with the ReverseStyle stylesheet, in Mathematica, which is the closest to a Dark theme that's available by default. However, the default font color for math output from MaTeX is black, which is ineligible against the Dark theme.

How can I change the font color to white for the MaTeX output?

I tried different versions of this:

```
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{color}\\color{red}"}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I change the font color to white for the MaTeX output?

```
<< MaTeX`

SetOptions[MaTeX,
 "Preamble"->{"\\usepackage{color}\\usepackage{amsmath}\\everymath{\\color{red}}"}]

MaTeX[Sin[x], Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I picked `red` above. Change that to `white` if you need.

Note that text used by Matex will also change color in the above. Here is an example

```
MaTeX["\\text{the result is }"<>ToString@TeXForm@Sin[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]